# How to pass function arguments when creating a list of tasks in R?

Tags: r, list, function, arguments, mclapply

I'm trying to create a list of tasks to run in R parallel using mclapply.

```
library(parallel)
tasks <- list(
  job1 = y(5),
  job2 = y(6)

)

# Using fork()
out <- mclapply( 
  tasks, 
  function(f) f(), 
  mc.cores = length(tasks) 
)
```

where y is for example:

```
y<-function(x){
a<-x^2
return(a)    
}
```

When creating the list, it executes the functions with arguments instead of only storing it as a list. (So this is before even arriving at the actual `mclapply`.)
If I use a function `y` without any arguments, this approach runs fine:

```
tasks <- list(
  job1 = y,
  job2 = y

)

# Using fork()
out <- mclapply( 
  tasks, 
  function(f) f(), 
  mc.cores = length(tasks) 
)
```

where y is for example:

```
y<-function(){
a<-5^2
return(a)    
}
```

So how do I store the functions *with arguments* in a list without executing the functions (until I tell them to in mclapply)?

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps:

```
tasks <- list(
    job1 <- substitute(y(5)),
    job2 <- substitute(y(6))
)
```

And then

```
out <- mclapply( 
    tasks,
    FUN=function(x) eval(x)), 
    mc.cores = length(tasks)
)
```

This should work with parallel operations, but it is impossible for me to test it since I'm using Windows.

Comment: Now it can create the list without executing the code. But now when I call mclapply, it then executes serially (as it would when defined in list in my original question).